# Is it safe to breastfeed an infant while being pregnant?

Tags: infant, safety, breastfeeding, pregnancy

If a mother gets pregnant within 2 months of a newborn, and wants to continue breastfeeding then what precautions she should take during the later trimesters? Will the newborn or the foetus be affected? And is it safe to breastfeed?

Answer (score 3):

Typically it is not the later trimesters you are worried about but the first trimester to be sure her body has had enough time to recover from the first pregnancy to carry a new child. The risk for miscarriage drastically decrease after the first trimester but I have heard of a 20-week miscarriage and it was a woman whose pregnancies were close together.

For breastfeeding, the body is already used to the hormones if she was breastfeeding before getting pregnant (vs. started when she conceived new baby) so it is safe to breastfeed during a pregnancy. However, since the new pregnancy is so close to the prior, I would definitely consult with a medical professional for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have breastfed through 2 pregnancies.

You do want to make sure you eat well & take your vitamins.  You can also ask for bloodwork to confirm you are getting adequate nutrition.  Your body will compromise you in order to maintain giving everything it needs to for your little ones & you don't want to end up nutrient deficient at the end of your pregnancy.

Typically there is no need to wean.  You should be made aware though that milk production for many women drops drastically, so exclusively breastfeeding may not be possible.  Your prolactin levels control your milk production & many women are unable to sustain high enough prolactin to have a full supply, some will dry up completely.  It is not possible to determine what will happen to a specific woman.  It varies greatly.  I have known women that did maintain a full supply.  That would be considered unusual though.  Most will see a drop, and for many it's significant.  For me I had almost no supply at all, both time.  My drops happened later, like midway, some see it sooner, some see it later, most will see supply return the last few weeks, I did not.  Mine didn't return until birth.

There are no galactogogues you can take for this drop.  The drop is hormonal.  There are foods of course that work as galactogogues that are safe, such as oatmeal, flax, malt, and I do find those are helpful, but they won't stop you from having a dip, they can just help however much they help.

If a mother has a history of preterm birth, she will likely also be asked to wean.  The data on this isn't conclusive, so it's a medical suggestion, but most Dr's will work with you if you do not desire to wean.

Comment: Really like your answers, Thorough and informed. +1

Answer (score 1):

Breastfeeding while pregnant is safe as long as you’re healthy and careful about having healthy diet and plenty of fluids. Most of the moms worry about whether they are eating enough to nourish the baby growing inside and for breastfeeding the nursling but our bodies are amazing they know how much to have. Have a healthy, well- balanced diet - eating when you’re hungry and drinking when thirsty is all that you need to do.

Breastmilk will be nutritionally sound throughout pregnancy but the taste of the milk changes and the breastmilk production decreases as the pregnancy progresses. These factors may lead the nursing child to wean on his or her own.  Better to consult your doctor to provide guidance and will confirm you whether to continue breastfeeding or not. It all depends on your health.